# What is the definition of differentiability in multivariable calculus?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

So it was my understanding that the definition of differentiability when it came to multivariable was the following: Where $f(x,y)$ is the function and $L(x,y)$ is the linear approximation.
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{|f (x, y) − L(x, y)|} {|\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}|}= 0$$

But when I was solving problems, there was a question that asked me to define what differentiability was and so I answered using the expression above. But in the answers they used this expression. So I was wondering what the difference was and why it looks like this. By the way the question was about checking if $f$ was differentiable at $(0,0)$ so I get why the denominator looks the way it does so I just don't get why the numerator looks the way it does.
$$\lim_{h_1,h_2 \to 0} \frac{f (x_0 + h_1, y_0 + h_2) − f (x_0, y_0) − L(h_1, h_2)} {\sqrt{h^2_1 + h^2_2}}= 0$$

Comment: Your definition is clearly wrong as the numerator does not depend on $h_1,h_2$ so the limit is always $\infty$ whenever the numerator is not zero.

Comment: I accidentally copy pasted and forgot to edit the h out, but I've edited it now so how about now?

Comment: That's an acceptable definition of differentiability for maps $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$

Comment: Alright but what is the difference between the one I used and they used? I thought we were supposed to take the function value minus the approximation and then the absolute value to show that the numerator is closer to 0 than then denominator but that is not exactly what they are doing right? If yes, well it is not that clear for me.

Comment: @Need_MathHelp Note that any linear function passes through the origin, i.e. $L(0,0) = 0$. If you have a function $f(x,y)$ such that $f(0,0) \neq 0$, then no $L$ approximates it. Instead, it should approximate $f(x,y) - f(0,0)$, which is trivially through the origin. Replace $(0,0)$ with an arbitrary $(x_0, y_0)$, and you've got the second (correct) definition.

Comment: @AlexJones could you please elaborate more on this part "Instead, it should approximate f(x,y)−f(0,0)". I don't really get it.

Comment: @Need_MathHelp Here's another way to look at it. We want to approximate $f$ with an affine function $A$, which is a linear function $L$ plus a constant $C$. In order for $A$ to approximate $f$ near $(0,0)$, we must first have $A(0,0) = f(0,0)$. Since $$A(0,0) = L(0,0) + C = C$$ this means $C = f(0,0)$ and so $A = L + f(0,0)$. The other condition is that $$[f(x,y) - A(x,y)]/\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \to 0$$ The numerator is $$f(x,y) - A(x,y) = f(x,y) - (L(x,y) + f(0,0)) = f(x,y) - f(0,0) - L(x,y)$$